# Android: Open app language settings from app itself

Tags: android

In Android 13, is there a way to open the new App info language settings using an intent in the app itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Solved, do something like this:

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_LOCALE_SETTINGS)
intent.data = Uri.fromParts("package", activity.packageName, null)
activity.startActivity(intent)
```

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_APP_LOCALE_SETTINGS